# Select внутри Select

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите как составить такой запрос

```
SELECT 
    SUM(leads.price) as allprice, 
    COUNT(leads.id) as open_leads, 
    COUNT(leads.id ГДЕ leads.id==666) 
FROM 
    users, 
    leads 
WHERE 
    leads.responsible_user_id=users.id
```

`COUNT(leads.id ГДЕ leads.id==666)` Т.е. посчитать количество, где id равен 666.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как один из возможных вариантов

```
SELECT 
    SUM(leads.price) as allprice, 
    COUNT(leads.id) as open_leads, 
    COUNT(IF(leads.id = 666, 1, NULL)) AS leads_666
FROM 
    users, 
    leads 
WHERE 
    leads.responsible_user_id = users.id
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(leads.price) as allprice, 
    COUNT(leads.id) as open_leads, 
    SUM(IF(leads.id=666,1,0)) 
FROM 
    users, 
    leads 
WHERE 
    leads.responsible_user_id=users.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT 
    SUM(leads.price) as allprice, 
    COUNT(leads.id) as open_leads, 
    COUNT(leads1.id) AS leads_666

FROM 
    leads, 

    leads as leads1

WHERE 
    leads.responsible_user_id = users.id 

AND leads1.id = 666
```